# Clear Combo box when user form is shown, I keep getting an error no matter where I put the clear command

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I have tried a number of ways to get the combobox I have on a userform to clear the value before showing. See code below, as my last attempt.

```
Sub Call_Userform4()

Sheet8.Activate
    Sheet8.ListObjects("Table1").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    Sheet8.ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    Sheet8.ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
        Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[Name (Last, First)]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
        Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
            With Sheet8.ListObjects("Table1").Sort
                .Header = xlYes
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With


    With UserForm4
      .StartUpPosition = 0
      .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
      .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
      .ComboBox1.Clear
      .Show
    End With
    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

```
Sub Call_Userform4()

  Sheet8.Activate
    Sheet8.ListObjects("Table1").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
    Sheet8.ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    Sheet8.ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Add2 _
        Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[Name (Last, First)]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
        Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortTextAsNumbers
            With Sheet8.ListObjects("Table1").Sort
                .Header = xlYes
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With


    With UserForm4
      .StartUpPosition = 0
      .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
      .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
      .Show
    End With
    
    With UserForm4.ComboBox1
        .Value = ""
    End With
    
End Sub
```